# creating topic in kafka : timed out CONNECTING issue with zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

i installed latest version of kafka on ubuntu 20.04 and when i try to create a topic , i have this error :

````
~/Kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic TutorialTopic

Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:271)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:125)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1948)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:378)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:56)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)```

i tried : 
- to modify zookeeper timeout connection time to 18000->60000 
- change zookeeper localhost:2181 to zookeeper zookeeper:2181

 but still same issue, do you know why please ?
````

Comment: Sounds like Zookeeper isn't running. And unclear what guide you're following, but the official Kafka quickstart documentation does not use `--zookeeper` argument

Comment: use ***--bootstrap-server*** instead of --zookeeper

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for your reply , i was using those tutorials :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-20-04

https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-20-04/

the official kafka quikstart command line were very short not complete do you have any link with appopriate command line with their meaning if possible thanks a lot

Comment: @sujin when i try your suggestion i have this error :

[2021-04-23 19:32:24,948] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:2181) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: follow the steps from apache Kafka quick start https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: Read the docs carefully. Particularly, the port numbers of what you're connecting to. More specifically, you never need to use Zookeeper outside of the `server.properties` file. With the most recent Kafka release, Zookeeper is also completely optional to start before the brokers (but Kafka needs to be explicitly configured to allow this)